# Polymer 1.x: paper-fab elevation not working?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

[In this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/corisahoqi/edit?html,output), I'm trying to add a `paper-fab` to my element.

I expect to see a shadow corresponding to the `elevation` property. But instead I see no shadow. All the elevations seem to have the same shadow (implied z-depth).

Is the problem with my code or the element?

http://jsbin.com/corisahoqi/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!---- >
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <!---- >
  Toggle below/above as backup when server is down
  <!---->
  <base href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/">
  <!---->
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-fab/paper-fab.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style>
    paper-fab {
      margin: 15px;
    }
  </style>
  <paper-fab icon="add" elevation="5"></paper-fab>
  <paper-fab icon="add" elevation="4"></paper-fab>
  <paper-fab icon="add" elevation="3"></paper-fab>
  <paper-fab icon="add" elevation="2"></paper-fab>
  <paper-fab icon="add" elevation="1"></paper-fab>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like a problem with the element. In the [documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-fab#property-elevation), it sounds as if it could be used the way you intend.

> The z-depth of this element, from 0-5. Setting to 0 will remove the shadow, and each increasing number greater than 0 will be "deeper" than the last

But then `elevation` property is read-only, so setting it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

`paper-fab` implements the `paper-button-behavior`. As @Maria mentioned `elevation` only returns the resulting elevation, it is readonly and can't be set.

You could try adding attributes like `raised` (?), `focused` (?), `disabled` (0), `active` (4), `pressed` (4), `receivedFocusFromKeyboard` (3) which should moify the elevation but that seems all that is supported (if at all).

Answer (score 1):

[I just found this issue report which confirms @Maria's answer](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-fab/issues/35).

So, as a patch, [I am adding the following CSS code (jsBin)](http://jsbin.com/hitororuja/edit?html,output) to add a shadow on hover to simulate the [material design elevation spec here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-raised-buttons).

> Button Elevation. Raised buttons have a default elevation of 2dp. On desktop, raised buttons can gain this elevation on hover.

```
paper-fab:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/hitororuja/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!---- >
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <!---- >
  Toggle below/above as backup when server is down
  <!---->
  <base href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/">
  <!---->
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-fab/paper-fab.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style>
    paper-fab:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
  </style>
  <paper-fab icon="send"></paper-fab>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```